# Passing Realm variable from other class to getView in the adapter

Tags: java, android, realm

In my main activity, I like to pass a result value from another class to my getview in my adapter.

I am able to pass to variable radioPosition to my adapter but cannot use it in my getView();

My question is how to pass the realm variable  from my Setting class to getview() in my School adapter

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ....
    Setting setting = realm.where(Setting.class).findFirst();
    //radioPosition is from Setting Class
    Integer radioPosition = setting.getPosition();
    RealmResults<School> schools = realm.where(School.class).findAll();
    //schools is from School Class

    final SchoolAdapter adapter = new SchoolAdapter(this, R.id.schools_list, schools, Integer radioPosition, true);
    ....
}
```

School Adaptor:

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<School> implements ListAdapter {

    ....
    public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults,  Integer radioPosition, boolean automaticUpdate) {

        super(context, realmResults,  automaticUpdate);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.school = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    .....
```

Comment: what do you mean by you cannot use it.  any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private int mRadioPosition;

  public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults,  Integer radioPosition, boolean automaticUpdate) {

        super(context, realmResults,  automaticUpdate);
        mRadioPosition = radioPosition;
    }
```

use `mRadioPosition` in your getView method. Let me know if I misunderstood your question..